# Grow selection inward?

Tags: selection-tools

Can you grow a selection inward. CTRL (+)&(-) will grow a selection but its outward

[image]

Comment: it doesn't seem to exist

Comment: Maybe an add-on can do that…or you wrote your own add-on ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this work for you? It doesn't "step" the selection area, unfortunately - it just gets everything within the loop.

[image: LoopInner]

Comment: Yes! that is the tool I needed, Don't know why it didn't work for me before. Glad you suggested trying it.